# Valgrind: отобразить все блоки в куче, которые остались на момент завершения программы

Tags: c++, c, valgrind

После того как программа, запущенная под Valgrind, завершается, он выводит различную статистику об использовании памяти и найденных ошибках. Среди этой информации может быть, например, такая:

```
==13679== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13679==     in use at exit: 72,936 bytes in 7 blocks
==13679==   total heap usage: 94 allocs, 87 frees, 77,520 bytes allocated
```

Отсюда следует, что на момент завершения программы, в куче осталось 7 блоков. Если на какие-то из них ссылок больше нет, то он выведет бектрейс, чтобы понять кто выделил утёкшую память в каждом случае, но если ссылки ещё есть, то такого не случится (и это вполне логично, зачем замусорировать вывод). Можно ли каким-нибудь ключом заставить его всё же вывести информацию о том, где был выделен каждый неутекший блок, который остался висеть в памяти после завершения программы?

Answer (score 1):

Мой valgrind (3.10.1) сообщает об этом:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    return !malloc(123);
}
```

Вывод (см. последнюю строку):

```
==4410== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4410==     in use at exit: 123 bytes in 1 blocks
==4410==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 123 bytes allocated
==4410== 
==4410== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4410==    definitely lost: 123 bytes in 1 blocks
==4410==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4410==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4410==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4410==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4410== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
```

То же самое, но с ключом `--leak-check=full`:

```
==4429== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4429==     in use at exit: 123 bytes in 1 blocks
==4429==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 123 bytes allocated
==4429== 
==4429== 123 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==4429==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4429==    by 0x4005EA: main (valgrind-test.c:5)
==4429== 
==4429== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4429==    definitely lost: 123 bytes in 1 blocks
==4429==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4429==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4429==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4429==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Стало быть, неосвобождённая память выделилась в функции main(), на 5 строке исходника. И точно, там :-)

P.S. А вообще я уже давно не вожусь с консолью для таких целей. Eclipse сам всё делает, включая навигацию по местам боевой славы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, в случае утечки Valgrind и у меня сообщает место, где память была выделена. Но, как я указал выше, меня интересует посмотреть, где было выделено то, что осталось на момент завершения работы программы, даже если на эту память остались ссылки и она не является утекшей.

Comment: Так у меня и не утечка показана.

Comment: `definitely lost: 123 bytes in 1 blocks`

Comment: `still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks`
У вас нет не утёкших блоков.

Comment: Именно то, что вы и хотите: "*и она не является утекшей*". Или я вас не очень понимаю. Приведите пример кода тогда.

Answer (score 0):

Такой ключ есть, достаточно посмотреть вывод valgrind --help.
valgrind --show-reachable=yes (я ещё пользуюсь --leak-check=full)